# Proof of invertible matrices

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, proof-explanation

Question:

Let $A$ and $B$ be two $n × n$ matrices. Prove the following assertions:

- If $AB$ is invertible, then both $A$ and $B$ are invertible.
- If $A^2B + 1973AB^2 + 2020AB + I_n = 0$, then both A and B are invertible.
- If the matrix $I_n + AB$ is invertible, then $I_n + BA$ is also invertible and $(I_n+BA)^{-1}=I_n-BCA$, where $C = (I_n + AB)^{−1}$

For the first part I think I can do something like this: Let $C = B(AB)^{−1}$ and $D = (AB)^{−1}A$. Then $AC = A(B(AB)^{−1}) = (AB)(AB)^{−1} = I$ and $DB = ((AB)^{−1}A)B = (AB)^{−1}(AB) =I$ and using the fact that $AB=I \Leftrightarrow BA=I$ gives us $C=A^{-1}$ and $D=B^{-1}$ and therefor $A$ and $B$ are both invertible. Is this an acceptable proof?

Can someone help with how to do the next two parts as well.  Thank you

Comment: For the first one: $AB$ is invertible if there exists $C$ st $(AB)C= I_n$, then $(AB)C=A(BC) $, so we have that $A (BC) = I_n$, i.e. $BC$ is the inverse of $A$. In the same way you can proof that $B$ is invertible.

Comment: The first one and third one have been asked before on this site. Also, rather than asking a single question with multiple parts, it might be better to ask three separate questions.

Comment: Regarding the second part, note that
$$
-A(A + 1973 B + 2020 I)B = I.
$$
Because $A[-(A + 1973 B + 2020 I)B] = I$, we can conclude that $A$ is invertible. By a similar argument, $B$ is invertible.

Comment: For the first one, you can prove te contrapositive easily enough. For if $A$ or $B$ are not invertible then $\det(A) = 0\ $ or $\det(B) = 0\implies \det(AB) = \det(A)\det(B) = 0\implies AB\ $ is not invertible.

Not sure about the other two just yet...

Comment: @AdamRubinson Your proof made unnecessary use of the result that $A$ is invertible iff $\operatorname{det}(A) \neq 0$. This also assumes that the matrices are over a field (which is not mentioned in the question).